# Retrieve type of base type without knowing its derived type

Tags: c#, reflection, inheritance

I need to get type of an object in base type. However I can't use BaseType, because I can't know how many levels of types the object has.

```
class Base
{
    public string Name { get set; }

    public DoAThing()
    {
        Type myType = GetType(); // returns Derived
    }
}

class Derived : Base
{
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        DoAThing();
    }
}
```

Is it possible to have in **myType** *Base* type?

Comment: Take a break, look at it tomorrow :)

Comment: Now, I know, how to do it, but I'll take the break anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public DoAThing()
    {
        Type myType = typeof(Base);
    }
```

Comment: I only just now realized how simple this is :) I guess I'm too tired to continue.

Comment: lol - we all do this. That's why its important to ask questions no matter how trivial you may think they are.

Comment: I was afraid it would require some mumbo-jumbo magic with Reflection :) Thanks, anyway.